# Can makeStyles be passed as a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, inline-styles

I have a component with a prop called `styling`.  I pass inline styling here.  I want to pass some styling I have written in `makeStyles`.  The style I want to pass is:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    fieldShape: {
        marginTop: "16px",
        [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
            width: "625px",
        },
    },
}))

...
const classes = useStyles();

<MyComponent styling={classes.fieldShape}/>

...
// My Component
const { styling } = props
<TextField style={styling}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the return value of the hook, returned from `makeStyles`, not the `makeStyles` itself as you described in the title.

You can pass it as deep prop

the hook from `makeStyles` does not return object with styles, it returns object with class names (strings), so it should be:

```
<TextField className={styling}/>   // className instead of style
```